# Communication between API and ASP.NET Core MVC web app - does it need "CORS" or not?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, cors, asp.net-core-webapi

This is my API:

```
[ApiController] 
[Route("[controller]")]
public class APIController : ControllerBase
{
    // [Authorize]
    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public string GetInformation() { return "Something !";  }
}
```

And this is my action in my ASP.NET Core 5 MVC web app:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetInfoFromAPI()
{
    using var client = new HttpClient();

    var requ = new HttpRequestMessage
    {
        Method = HttpMethod.Get,
        RequestUri = new Uri("http://localhost:5000/API/GetInformation"),
        Content = new StringContent(string.Empty, Encoding.UTF8, MediaTypeNames.Application.Json)
    };

    var resp = await client.SendAsync(requ);
    var Result = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    return View("GetInfoFromAPI", Result); 
}
```

Amazing! How does it work? Why does it work? I didn't enable "Cross-Origin Requests" (CORS) in my API startup !

If any `HttpGet/Post/...` from any origin can get information from my API, so what is CORS? What is the use for it?

Comment: CORS policy used by a browser, your code talks 'backend-to-backend'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XMLHttpRequest cannot load XXX No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553500/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-xxx-no-access-control-allow-origin-header)

Comment: @YehorAndrosov please explain more
What do you mean "by browser"?
Do you mean CORS is only for javascript?

Comment: each browser has its own security policies to protect users. CORS is one of them. It is just a set of headers that tells browser if server wants us to follow rules. Browser automatically follows them and does not load images or fails to make calls to other resources if CORS policy fails. It is not javascript only, since CORS policy also affects images, iframes, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To further explain what Yehor said in comments:

Cross-Origin Resource Sharing is a security feature in **web browsers** whose purpose is to help restrict scripts on one origin (domain) to make requests to another origin. This mechanism was developed to mitigate attacks such as cross-site request forgery (CSRF/XSRF), cross-site scripting (XSS), and other cross-origin attacks. Upon recognizing a cross-origin request, the browsers send an HTTP request to the target server with an "Origin" header. The server then responds with CORS headers indicating whether or not the request is acceptable or not, which depends on the server's CORS policy configuration.

In your case, the CORS policy is not relevant, as two servers are communicating in a back-channel (machine to machine) without involving a browser. In other words, since CORS is a mechanism that is applied at the level of the web browser (front-channel), it does not apply when the two servers are communicating in bnack-channel without a browser involved. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here's [the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-8.0) to show how Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is enabled in an ASP.NET Core app.

> **Browser** security **prevents a web page** from making requests to a
> different domain than the one that served the web page. This
> restriction is called the **same-origin** policy. The same-origin policy
> prevents a malicious site from reading sensitive data from another
> site. Sometimes, you might want to allow other sites to make
> cross-origin requests to your app.

Therefore, the **error is reported by the browser**. In your scenario, it's the mvc project(a kind of server app) to call the web api(is also a kind of server app),there's no browser interactive here, and that's why we don't get CORS error. By the way, test the API via tools like postman won't get CORS error too, because CORS is implemented by browsers on the client side which is essentially used to **block  accessing cross-origin resources**.

Different IP or port will cause CORS error too, and that's why we have `.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod()`